# SVG in button not showing background correctly in React

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass

I am adding buttons to my project and am having difficulty figuring out why the background around the svg is showing both the background of the button and the page's background in a square around the svg.

Any idea what how to fix my scss/css? The [code sandbox is here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dream-vbjyq?file=/src/styles.scss:0-508)

[image: Button with svg]

```
* {
  background: lightcoral;
}

button {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background: blue;
  }
}
//Home button behavior is here
.home-button {
  margin: 1rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.home-pic {
  border: none;
  width: 2.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you fix it:

```
* {
  background: lightcoral;
}

button {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background: blue;
    
    // apply hover effect to the home button
    .home-pic{
      background: blue;
    }
  }
}
//Home button behavior is here
.home-button {
  // do you really need these styles?
  // margin: 1rem;
  // border: none;
  // outline: none;
}
.home-pic {
  border: none;
  
  // I added these styles
  width: 1.1rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: That is much better. Thank you. And what If I just wanted the house without the button look?

Comment: your house icon is wrapper in button element. that button element is what is styling your icon. change the button element into something else or change its style. Accept it as the answer if it helps